# How to get H.239 working as SIP server, not found in Asterisk or Yate or SipX or FreeSwitch

Tags: java, linux, centos, sip, asterisk

I was writing a small Java, application for peer to peer using SIP, which will be handling H.239 like all other common standards. But while working i wanted to have a Server who supports it to rely on. But so far i tried with Asterisk/Yate/SipX/FreeSwitch, and none does or allow this feature yet.

So, my question is for further testing and making my application compatible with SIP servers. Which SIP server i can use to test H.239?

Thanks a lot in advanced.

**Follow up:**

- Hammering my head, h.239 is a nightmare, if you are a developer dreaming SIP ( none can do that: asterisk, yate, freeswitch, sipx, openSIP, etc etc)
- Protocol must be, SIP (BFCP), H.323 (H.239), ISDN (H.230)
- No where in international standard found SIP will not do that, as SIP is protocol, so is H.323/ISDN, existing hardware does and there specification says following:

  > The Presentation function and the Dual
  >   Video function support
  >   videoconferencing over both IP (H.323
  >   protocol) and ISDN (H.320 protocol),
  >   or a combination of the two. Both
  >   functions can also be used in H.235
  >   encrypted communication for when
  >   secure videoconferencing is required.
- If you read this article, somehow by mistake, from my experience the only advise would be, make sure what you are up to!! otherwise you will just buy all those www.google.com fastest search engine results, full of confusing hardwares, and get trapped to fine tune with your voip switch which is mostly now a days SIP.

Solution? http://www.opalvoip.org/wiki/

- Get the dream out of your mind to have H.239 in SIP, thats not gonna work
- I wonder why the hell SIP was really necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SIP shouldn't even be working with H.239.
H.239 is the dual video specification that is used by H.323. It is negotiated on top of H.245 messages.
SIP doesn't have H.245 - it uses SDP instead, so I can't see how you can achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your information is very confusing. Please have a look: http://old.nabble.com/Re:--Sip--Questions-about-the-status-of-dual-video-feature-in-SIP-td22252846.html

Comment: Right, it says that H239 is a conferencing protocol, and it says that the same features could be implemented in SIP. Other than the possibility that SIP could perhaps provide the same features, these 2 protocols are not particularly related. However - this is not programming related and doesn't belong on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @nos: Thanks, when you write or configure a switch server module and write at the same time client module, its lot of programming related. Where none of the resource have clear information about H.239. Would you mind just writing one from today or now? And feel the same problems how much information is missing regarding this and how much confusing it is?

Comment: @nos: i have already written SIP java stacks and few audio codecs. But i am moving to video implementation in native java. My java application (which is A to Z SIP), and i want to integrate to H.239 for presentation and integration with a hardware codec from Sony. But what i see now, which is impossible to have my SIP application of java to H.239.

Comment: @IamSonOfRaja: I almost forgot. On our blog there's a post explaining data collaboration (=dual video) in video conferencing where it comes to SIP and H.323. Check it out - it might assist you further in what you need to do http://blog.radvision.com/videooverenterprise/2009/09/15/data-collaboration-in-video-conferencing/